# Is the linear combination of least square estimators in linear regression normally distributed?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, least-squares

I am reading Mathematical Statistics with Applications by Wackerly et al. (7th edition). In Chapter 11, the book discusses linear models and least squares, specifically $Y = \beta_0+\beta_1x+\epsilon$ where $E(\epsilon)=0$ and $Var(\epsilon)=\sigma^2$, with $E(Y)=\beta_0+\beta_1x$ being deterministic.

The book derives $\hat\beta_0=\bar Y - \hat\beta_1\bar x$ and $\hat\beta_1=\frac{\sum(x_i-\bar x)(Y_i-\bar Y)}{\sum(x_i - \bar x)^2}$ as estimators of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ respectively from minimizing the SSE. The book states if $\epsilon$ is normally distributed, then each $Y_i$ from an independent sample is normally distributed and  $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ are also normally distributed since they are linear combinations of $Y_i$. I am assuming this is true based on [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables)?

However, the book later goes further to state that $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ being normal implies that a linear combination $\hat\theta = a_0\hat\beta_0 + a_1\hat\beta_1$ is also normal. This confuses me since $Cov(\hat\beta_0 ,\hat\beta_1)=\frac{-\bar x\sigma^2}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}$ may not be zero, which means for $\hat\theta$ to be normal, the joint distribution of $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ must be normal (per [this proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Correlated_random_variables)) but the book makes no reference to the joint distribution. Is it always true that $\hat\theta$ is normally distributed? If so, how is it shown?

Comment: It's all the same proof and it's simple: $(\hat\beta_0,\hat\beta_1)$ is a linear transformation of the jointly normal vector $\epsilon$ and therefore is jointly normal, *QED.*

Comment: You can see all the linked threads here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347628/joint-distribution-of-least-square-estimates-hat-alpha-hat-beta-in-a-simpl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **yes**. This is because least squares estimates themselves are jointly normal distributed which can be seen by applying the *linear transformation theorem for the multivariate normal distribution* ([Proof](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mvn-ltt)):

$$
x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma) \quad \Rightarrow \quad y = Ax + b \sim \mathcal{N}(A\mu + b, A \Sigma A^\mathrm{T})
$$

Using matrix notation for linear regression, the distribution of the data is:

$$
y = X\beta + \varepsilon, \; \varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I_n)
$$

$$
\Rightarrow \quad y \sim \mathcal{N}(X\beta, \sigma^2 I_n)
$$

If we apply *ordinary least squares* ([Proof](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mlr-ols)), the distribution of the estimates is:

$$
\hat{\beta} = (X^\mathrm{T}X)^{-1} X^\mathrm{T}y
$$

$$
\Rightarrow \hat{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}\left((X^\mathrm{T}X)^{-1} X^\mathrm{T}X\beta, \sigma^2 (X^\mathrm{T}X)^{-1} X^\mathrm{T} X (X^\mathrm{T}X)^{-1} \right) = \mathcal{N}\left( \beta, \sigma^2 (X^\mathrm{T}X)^{-1} \right)
$$

Then, a linear combination of the least squares estimates is distributed as:

$$
\Rightarrow c^\mathrm{T} \hat{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}\left( c^\mathrm{T} \beta, \sigma^2 c^\mathrm{T} (X^\mathrm{T}X)^{-1} c \right)
$$

In your special case (a.k.a. "simple linear regression"), the quantities would be:

$$
X = \begin{bmatrix} 1_n & x \end{bmatrix}, \; \beta = \begin{bmatrix} \beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \end{bmatrix}, \; c = \begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \end{bmatrix}, \; c^\mathrm{T} \hat{\beta} = \hat{\theta}
$$

$$
( \text{and of course} \quad y = Y, \; \varepsilon = \epsilon )
$$

Comment: Just discovered that my answer is roughly equivalent to this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/347642/270304; and this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/133333/270304.

Comment: For the case where $X^TX$ is not invertible, does this still hold? I considered substituting the general pseudoinverse of $X$ to replace occurrences of $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ but I'm actually not sure whether the pseudoinverse in this context is always non-singular. Per [Lemma 5](https://mast.queensu.ca/~stat353/slides/5-multivariate_normal17_4.pdf) it seems the joint distribution of $\hat\beta$ doesn't exist when the covariance matrix is singular.

Comment: Yes. Ordinary least squares requires that the design matrix has full rank, see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/138342/270304.