What weighted average is OLS?
How can we find what sort of weighted-average a covariate is from a linear regression fitted with least squares?
Consider the model
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \tau + \sum_{j = 2}^k \beta_{j} X_{j} + \epsilon
$$
where $Y$ is a continuous variable, $\tau$ is a binary variable {0, 1}, and $X$ is a categorical variable that consists of $k + 1$ categories where $j = k + 1$ is the referent category. For simplicity, let's assume $X$ denotes state. If our object of interest is the coefficient for $\tau$, we might be interested in the relative contribution of each state (category of $X$).
It is well known that $\beta_1$ is a weighted average where each category $j$ of $X$ receives the following weight.
$$
\tag{1}
\frac{w(j)}{\sum{w(j{})}} 
$$
where

$w(j) = q(j) \cdot e(j) \cdot (1 - e(j))$ with
$q(j) = \frac{N(j)}{N}$ is the proportion of units in each state
$e(j) = \frac{N_{\tau = 1}(j)}{N(j)}$ is the proportion of units where $\tau = 1$ in each state.

Now consider the addition of an additional covariate
$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \tau + \beta_2 Z + \sum_{j = 3}^k \beta_{j} X_{j} + \epsilon
$$
where $Z$ is a continuous variable. When $Z$ is independent of $\tau$, then (asymptotically) (1) still holds. What about the case where $Z$ is not independent of $\tau$. Is it possible to find an equation like (1) where we can decompose the individual contribution of each $j$ in $X$ to the weighted average for $\beta_1$? Is there perhaps a way to use the Frisch-Waugh-Lovell Theorem to find these weights?

You cannot decompose the solution like this unless your explanatory variables are uncorrelated.  (This has nothing to do with dependencies between $Y$ and the explanatory variables.)  Geometrically, you are asking for a general rule to "explain" the length of one side of any arbitrary triangle in terms of the other two sides: evidently, the angle matters.

@whuber thanks! I meant to say when $X_2$ is independent (or not) of $\tau$, not $Y$. I've edited this now. And I'm happy with a formula for the weights that includes the angles.

„each factor $j$ of $X_1$“ what does that mean?

"the proportion of units" what units?

If $X_1$ is a categorical variable then the expression $\beta_2 X_1$ is not very clear.

The angles are given by the correlations among the variables.  The Normal Equations express everything there is to know compactly.  Here's a focused search to get you started.

@SextusEmpiricus, thanks for the comments. I've edited the notation.

The regression can be written as in matrix form
$$\hat\beta = (X_TX)^{-1}X^T y$$
and for a single coefficient this is like a weighted sum of the observations
$$\hat\beta_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_{ij}y_j$$
with the weights being the elements of the matrix in a single row
$$w_{ij} = \left[(X^TX)^{-1} X^T\right]_{ij}$$
If you have clearly specified simplifications/conditions then you can simplify the matrix.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133312/distribution-of-linear-combination-of-ols-regression-coefficients

Hmm. I don't see how the vector of weights from the normal equation would get you to something like (1) above. You get the individual contribution of each $i$, but how would make sense of that for $j$ without first utilizing $y_i$?

@num_39 for simple regression matrices with many repetitions, those $w_{ij}$ will be the same for each category. However, if you are adding an additional continuous variable then this will not be the case anymore.

Yes this is clear. I was wondering if there was clever decomposition or approximation but I suppose not.

Because the solution of the Normal equations is a linear combination of $y,$ a fortiori it's in the form (1).  The only thing to show would be that the denominator of (1) is nonzero -- but I don't believe that's necessarily the case without additional assumptions.
